# Ionic Native Date Picker not working on Android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I am using a Cordova plugin from [IonicNative](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/date-picker/) page.

I use two different selects, one to select a date, and another to select
the time. Both work fine on iOS but with Android I have two problems.

1. On Date Picker there is no bounds so that the old dates cannot be selected, even though I do pass that in controller.

   ```
   showDatePicker(){
   this.datePicker.show({
     date: this.dateChosen,
     mode: 'date',
     minDate: this.today,
     maxDate: this.maxDay,
     allowOldDates: false        }).then(
     date => {
       this.dateChosen = m(date);
     },
     err => alert('Error occurred while getting date: ' + err)
   );}
   ```

   I used moment.js for date/time generation, so `this.dateChose = moment();`
   It is not the source of the problem, same for `this.today` and `this.maxDay`

I tried using javascript's `Date()` but it did not change anything, on Android I could still select whichever date I wanted

2. More important problem is that Time Picker does *not work* on Android at ALL

   ```
   showTimePicker(){
   this.datePicker.show({
     date: this.timeChosen,
     mode: 'time',
     is24Hour: true,
     minuteInterval: 15,
     allowOldDates: false        }).then(
     date => {
       this.timeChosen = m(date);
     },
     err => alert('Error occurred while getting date: ' + err)
   );}
   ```

On iOS I have no problem and it works just fine, but on Android it goes to err state with err message being `For input string "2017-07-10T13:10.24.213Z"`.
I changed the input to pass it int of unix time but it just changed the err message. Anyone knows what to do??

Comment: I try to use it in 2 project, always the same error: "Class not found"
Great ! No more info and nobody seems to have this problem...

Answer (score 4):

I have a usefull answer :)

```
  import { DatePicker } from '@ionic-native/date-picker'
  //...
  constructor(public datePicker: DatePicker) {}
  //...
  public toPickDateTime() {

    let minDays = 2
    let maxDays = 365

    this.datePicker
      .show({
        mode: 'datetime',
        date: this.getNowAndAdd(2, true),
        minDate: this.getNowAndAdd(2),
        maxDate: this.getNowAndAdd(5),
        is24Hour: true,
        androidTheme: this.datePicker.ANDROID_THEMES.THEME_HOLO_DARK,
      })
      .then(
        date => console.log(date),
        err => console.log(err)
      );
  }

  private getNowAndAdd(nbDays, forceDate = false): any
  {
    var date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (nbDays * 24 * 3600 * 1000))

    return (this.platform.is("android") && !forceDate) ? date.getTime() : date
  }
```

You need to know the minDate and maxDate are "buged" and nobody dont care ^^.
On android you need to pass an integer but on ios you need to pass a date

I say it's a bug because "ionic" and "cordova" have to do this parsing in a perfect world.

As it doesnt' this trick can solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I solved it by completely removing cordova plugin and instead using the Ionic's own component `ion-datetime` for both cases. Now it shows the slider wheel instead of calendar on Android, but I am fine with that.

Also adding limitations like min, max dates was easy, dynamically possible and well documented on [Ionic Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/)

Answer (score 0):

To use the `ionic-native/date-picker` plugin you need to run project on the device, because the plugin uses the cordova. If you use `ionic serve` to run project, you seen a message in console like below:

```
Ionic Native: tried calling DatePicker.show, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to a) run in a real device or simulator and b) include cordova.js in your index.html
```